# How can I use auto username and password save in html?

Tags: html

I want to save a username and a password in my html page. I'm using now input type="password" for the password, but the username is what? input type="text" or what? Because if I want to save the password, the username is not saved.

Comment: This question is hard to answer. Saving it in pure html is not possible. Are you only using html? Or mabye any other languages like php.
Also how do you want to save it? Into a Database? Or into a file?
Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: A username is generally a text input, yes.  Because usernames are generally text.  What does that have to do with "saving" anything?  What are you "saving" and where are you "saving" it?  What specifically isn't working in your code?

Comment: No no no. The tipical password save from Google Chrome. If you type your password, Google Chrome will recommend to save the password. But what type of input I can use for username/email?

Comment: @LogRol: Once again, typically a username input is an `input type="text"`.  If it's always an email then you could use `type="email"`.  There are a variety of types you can use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input  Which one you choose is up to you and how you use that value.  If you are encountering an *actual problem* somewhere, we can't know anything about that problem unless you describe and demonstrate it.  So far all you're asking is what type of `<input>` is used for text.  That would be `type="text"`.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. It's working. Thank you for all your help! Best to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the answer to your question is the text. And if you want to you use autocomplete feature available in google chrome. Add autocomplete attribute to your input tag and it can help save the data in chrome cache.

[W3 specification of autocomplete attribute](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/html/H98)
Example:

```
<input id="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" ... >
```